# Separating Node.js applications into multiple

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, passport.js, microservices

So me being stupid didn't think about that I build my whole application front to back on one Node.js application instance. Now I have to figure out how to make each thing its own service. My current application has the front end (main site), front end (application/software part) and the backend all together. I need to figure out how best to separate these into front/main, auth, front/app and backend/app

How would I even go about doing this? I would post code examples but I am sure that is too long and would not let me thanks to a code to word ratio on here. The git repo is not public either so can't post that.

My stack is mongo, node.js and express, I am using passport.js to go with it also.

Comment: First off, why do you need to break each into their own service?  What goal are you trying to accomplish by doing that?  Then, one early part of understanding a multi-process architecture is knowing what data needs to be accessed by what parts and what data needs to be shared?  There's really not much for us to go on at all in your question for how you should architect that or even what you're trying to accomplish by splitting it up.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer might be to break up the parts logically into modules and then require them where needed.

Without knowing how your code is organized, here is a simple example that might get you moving in the right direction.

### Before

**index.js**

```
// index.js
'use strict';

const answer = 42;
const run = (output) => console.log(`Inside: run() - ${output}`);

run(answer); // Inside: run() - 42
```

### After

**index.js**

```
// index.js
'use strict';

const process = require('./modules/process');
const answer = 42;

process.run(answer); // Inside: process.run() - 42
```

**modules/process.js**

```
// modules/process.js
'use strict';

const run = (output) => console.log(`Inside: process.run() - ${output}`);

module.exports = { run };
```

### Steps

1. Create the module file. One option is to create a `modules` folder and put the module files in there.
2. Add the `require` statement at the top of the original `index.js` file.
3. In the new module file, move over a function.
4. Add the function to the `module.exports`.
5. Change the call to use the module version.

**Pointers**

- Baby steps: Move one function at a time and make sure that you haven't broken anything before moving the next function.
- Try it: There are many variations and ways to organize the code. Don't be too afraid that you will "do it wrong".

Comment: This sounds more like an exercise in breaking code into modules that all still run in the same process.  I don't think that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 You’re right. This is an exercise in breaking code into modules. As you commented above, it is not clear what the OP's goal is. Even if they intend to make completely separate services, it sounded like they will need to break the code out.